# How to reset Network Dataset in Network Analysis Properties with python (arcpy)?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst

I have mxd which is used to upload network service. 
Mxd uses our network dataset to do Closest Facility and Routing Analysis. All features of this Network Dataset are listed in the table of content as layers. 
This mxd is used to create service definition file for our portal.

I have a script which updates layers in this mxd with the latest road network and uploads a new service definition file. Script works fine.

However I have recently realized that updating the layers in the map does not actually updates the sources for network dataset that is used for the analysis.

Does anyone know how to update source for the Network Dataset with python? 
I have inserted below the screenshot of the menu (with button highlighted in red). This is what I am looking to do with arcpy.

[image: Netwrok Analyst -> Source - > Set]

Comment: What is in your script?  If it does not have `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` then that is something that I would try.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a snippet the code you're trying to use